# Adding the new data-type to numpy

Tags: numpy, scipy

I would like to create 8bit representation for floating-point in NumPy.
Numpy has great documentation, and I found an article which describes how process of adding new data-type looks like:
 https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/c-info.beyond-basics.html#user-defined-data-types

 But unfortunately, this is a bit too hard for me. I know that NumPy comes with 24 builtin data-types. So when NumPy developers went through adding all of that builtin data-types, they went through the same process as I do right now? So can I find somewhere, fully-described example how this process looks like?

Comment: I've written a few and put them on github here: https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/numtypes.  There are links to more examples and docs at the bottom of README.md in that repo.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser.Thank you so much, you saved tons of time.